# Why do I get an AutoAction message in my Manipulate output?

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

The code below basically downloads and manipulates some data. I won't show it all because it's too long. But if you find that it must be provided to help you with answering my question, please let me know.

An unwanted message appears on top of my buttons(please see picture): `Manipulator[19,{0.95}, AutoAction -> False]`. How can I get rid of it?

```
Manipulate[Module[_data manipulation_],{bank,\[Tau]},{{bank,19},{15->"BAC", 16->"JPM", 
17->"WFC", 18->"WB", 19->"C"}},{{\[Tau], 0.95}, {0.95 -> "VaR", 0.5 -> "Median"}}]
```

`bank`selects the rows that correspond to the institution I'm analysing and `\[Tau]` selects the quantile of a distribution. There is nothing `Dynamic` in my gui, I believe.

[image]

Comment: In your code when you have `$\tau$` it should be `\[Tau]` which is displayed as τ. BTW, it looks like you are specifying the manipulator variable `bank` twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Gustavo. So how am I supposed to code it? The other variants I tried resulted in errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Manipulate[Module[{}, {stuff}]; (* not comma *) {bank, \[Tau]}, 
  {{bank, 19}, {15 -> "BAC", 16 -> "JPM", 17 -> "WFC", 18 -> "WB", 19 -> "C"}}, 
  {{\[Tau], 0.95}, {0.95 -> "VaR", 0.5 -> "Median"}}]
```

[image]

With `,` in place of  `;` the expression `{bank, \[Tau]}` is seen as a control.